# How do I get user input in a custom action in Rasa?

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa

I am extracting questions from database because It's relatively large dump of data and I wanted to know if there was a way to extract user input from custom actions.
I'm using Rasa SDK 2.0.0a1 .
Solutions I have tried:

- tracker.latest_message["text"]
- tracker.latest_message.text
- tracker.latest_message.get("text")
  Any other solutions would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the latest user message from the current state of the tracker:

```
current_state = tracker.current_state()
latest_message = current_state["latest_message"]["text"]
```

An even easier way to do that is by using the method:
`tracker.latest_message['text']`